# plld Prolog C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, swi-prolog

I have a large Prolog program with lots of predicates. I need to connect to this Prolog code from C++ (VS2008) to obtain certain query results. So I am not trying to embed Prolog in C++ as a logicasl engine, but for my C++ program to connect to my Prolog code, consult (compile) it, obtain query results, and pass them back to C++.

Running the following command at the VS2008 Command Prompt generates so many errors:

```
plld -o myprog.exe mycpp.cpp mypl.pl
```

Is there any way I can get my C++ program to consult my Prolog program, by including a command or makefile, etc...?

I am aware that if you use VS2008, you are better off not using plld, so I am trying to include everything in one master C++ program, then press F5 to build and compile, and then call Prolog, then C++, and so on...

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to pass the necessary compiling and linking flags to plld that it will pass to your VC++ compiler. The graphical interface automatically calls the compiler with a lot of flags, like include path and such, which you have to figure out first. Look under the project properties.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been through the Project Properties.  I'm not trying to avoid using VS2008 IDE.  I'm only trying to avoid using plld at the prompt (to compile my Prolog and C++ codes against each other).  But obviously I need to do it in my code, perhaps through a dll.  Can you tell me in detail how I can make a dll for a VS2008 Solution file please?